# How to load correctly a SPC56AP54 dump in Ghidra or IDA?

Tags: ida, ghidra, firmware-analysis

I am trying to analyze a SPC56AP54 MCU. I try to load it in Ghidra by selecting "MPC8270", but probably this is wrong and the disassembly looks bad. Can someone please give a hint if there is something I can do to disassemble this MCU with the current versions of IDA or Ghidra (or any other similar tool)?
Here is a link to the flash dump: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/18fkql3ftulef0v0qqqwv/SPC56AP54.zip?rlkey=339i2ym6i4126dnxlnhx8947m&dl=0